# Where do Instagram/Facebook store images internally?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Like the title says. In an iPhone, in what directory do Instagram/Facebook (and similar applications) store the images they downloaded at runtime?

When is that directory wiped?

Comment: I am not sure what facebook and Instagram do, But what I do is I have written a asynchronous image downloader which will download the image from the server and save in document directory. Next time when the same request need to send I will first check in .plist file that image is already there or not and if there i will show from there. And I will maintained a variable for deleting the file say 1 day.Maintained a .plist file for all the downloaded images with saving time and the URL fetched from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For non permanent images (e.g. post thumbnails but not user profile pics) I would imagine they get stored in the `<Application_Home>/Library/Caches`, other content probably goes in Documents

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to know what facebook or instagram do, but If I understand your question right, you want to download images asynchronously from web and cache them. For that u can use a third party class to handle the caching instead of writing your own, I would suggest [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage).